# Sending JSON Object on AJAX Request, Undefined on Server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax

I am using an XMLHttpRequest like this:

```
xml.send(JSON.stringify({ingredients: this.state.ingredients}));
```

to send an object (`this.state.ingredients`) to the server. I'm pretty confident that it is being sent correctly, because in Chrome Dev Tools under Network tab the request payload looks right. However I've tried a bunch of different things on the server to grab that object and I can't get anything but `undefined`.

Currently it looks like this:

```
router.post('/recipes/:recipe_id/add', function(req, res) {
  let ingredients = req.ingredients;
  console.log(ingredients)
}
```

but I've also tried using `JSON.parse` among other attempts. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi please you should first do something like this to debug before the xml.send console.log(this.state.ingredients); This is to ensure that the this.state.ingredients isn't the one that is undefined

Comment: Have you tried logging the contents of `req`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use express, install body-parser :

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

and use it :

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and try :

```
let ingredients = req.body.ingredients;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the used framework, your Request Body will probably be in `req.body`